# CUDA and driver: can I remove driver or change resolution?

Tags: 12.10, cuda

I have just installed CUDA. all 3 parts (samples,toolkit,driver). do I have to have this NVIDIA driver installed?

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 630] (rev a1)
```

it has been installed but neauveau has been uninstalled and on my ubuntu 12.10 only neauveau gives nice resolution. or other option: haw to change resolution with this driver? in settings->display there are only 2 options: 1024 or 800 but I 'd like higher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install this:

> NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library from
>   nvidia-current

resolution is ok (great as before) and CUDA works.
see related post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259325/installing-cuda-on-ubuntu-12-10-geforce-gt-630)